# How to set Kendo UI Scheduler control's weekview start day to Monday?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Is it possible to set the Kendo UI Scheduler's weekview and/or monthview to start on Monday instead of Sunday?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, in the kendo.all.min.js file you can set firstDay:1. By default it is set to 0, making Sunday the first day displayed.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not supported yet. Probably in a new version.

Comment: OK, I think I found a solution, but still don't know if it's the best approach? In the kendo.all.min.js file being referenced, there are standards defined for calendars

Comment: in the culture settings in the kendo script files.                    i.e.   calendars:{standard:{days:{names:["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"],namesAbbr:["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"],namesShort:["Mo","Tu","We","Th","Fr","Sa","Su"]}     <br/> I basically just moved "Sunday" to the end and saved the file.   This should work until upgrading to a later version.  Is it not possible to add an extra .JS file to override the ones from the Kendo library?